# Restoring potential of atoms in a solid

Tags: crystal-structure, atoms, solid-state-chemistry

Above $\pu{0 K}$ the atoms in a solid are vibrating. However, what kind of potential restores each atom in the starting position?

Consider the crystal lattice of NaCl. The potential energy of a $\ce{Na+}–\ce{Cl-}$ pair is

$$E(r) = -\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\frac{e^2M}{r^2} + \frac{B}{r^m},\tag{1}$$

where $M$ is the Madelung constant, $B$ and $m$ are the material-depending constants.

When a $\ce{Na+}$ ion and a $\ce{Cl-}$ ion get very close, the second term of the equation is increased very much and it becomes the restoring potential in the vibration of the ions.

In a  crystal lattice made of $\ce{Si}$ atoms above $\pu{0 K}$ each atom oscillates at the Debye frequency from its starting position as part of a quantum harmonic oscillator:

$$\frac{-h^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi(x) + V(x)\Psi(x) = hf\left(\frac 1 2 + N\right)\Psi(x),\tag{2}$$

and $x=0$ will be the position of equilibrium of the atom.

What kind of expression is $V(x)?$ To which power do we raise the variable $x$?

Comment: Please edit this and typeset your equations. The GIF images are less amenable to searching.

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Come on, you've been a member on this site for 8 months now. Read the docs. You give, you get.

Comment: Zero kelvin is not OK, it's $\pu{0 K}$. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: Can I ask this?The LaTeX editor generates a string of characters can I copy paste it instead  of uploading the image?

Comment: @JunSeo-He In general, no. LaTeX and MathJax are vastly different systems that happen to share similar markup. Even if you are a LaTeX user, there is little to no reason to use code generators as usually they fail at something slightly more advanced than a couple of fractions, or produce horrible non-semantic code. And keep in mind copypasting *anything* without understanding how it has been produced is a bad idea.

Comment: @JunSeo-He You have just given two examples for $V(x)$. So what is exactly your question?

Comment: What is a empirical formula for the attraction/repulsion of 2 atoms covalently bonded?